# SELECT values from XML column from SQL server specifying WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, xml, search, where-clause

I have a SQL table similar to this:

```
create table #Temp_xml
(
ID int not null,
Name varchar(10) null,
Step XML null
)
truncate table #Temp_xml
Insert INTO #Temp_xml (ID, Name, Step) Values
(1, 'Query 1',
'<LoadData>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 1</StepName>
    <StepType>Validation</StepType>
    <Result>PAST</Result>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 2</StepName>
    <Command>SELECT colA, colB FROM Mytbl</Command>
    <ID>888</ID>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 3</StepName>
    <Command>Truncate table tblABC</Command>
    <ID>103</ID>
   </Step>
 </LoadData>')


 Insert INTO #Temp_xml (ID, Name, Step) Values
(2, 'Query 2',
'<LoadData>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 1</StepName>
    <StepType>Validation</StepType>
    <Result>True</Result>
    <ID>112</ID>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 2</StepName>
    <Command>SELECT colA, colB FROM Mytbl</Command>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 3</StepName>
    <Command>Exec dbo.MyStoredproc</Command>
   </Step>
 </LoadData>')
 Insert INTO #Temp_xml (ID, Name, Step) Values
(3, 'Query 3',
'<LoadData>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 1</StepName>
    <StepType>Validation</StepType>
    <Result>False</Result>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 2</StepName>
    <Command>SELECT colA, colB FROM Mytbl</Command>
    <ID>666</ID>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 3</StepName>
    <Command>Update tblXyz set colA = ''999'' FROM tbl_test</Command>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepName>Step 4</StepName>
    <Command>Truncate table tblABC</Command>
    <ID>678</ID>
   </Step>
 </LoadData>')
```

I need to search column Step from #temp_xml for row which has ID = 678. The following query will not return data since 
 there are more than one  nodes.

```
  select * from #Temp_xml
 WHERE step.value('(/LoadData/Step/ID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = 678
```

However, since the 2nd time ID appears, I get the desired results:

```
 select * from #Temp_xml
 WHERE step.value('(/LoadData/Step/ID)[2]', 'varchar(max)') = 678
```

My question is, how can I make this search more generic, so that I do not have to put the occurence in 
 square brackets [ ]?

Comment: BTW, you should consider variable tables over temp tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.exist(...)` function with an XPath query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM #Temp_xml
WHERE step.exist('/LoadData/Step[ID="678"]') = 1
```

... if you need to pass in a variable to the query you can do it like this ...

```
DECLARE @id INT = 678;    
SELECT *
FROM #Temp_xml
WHERE step.exist('/LoadData/Step[ID=sql:variable("@id")]') = 1;
```

Comment: @SilverFish, if this works for you, it would be kind to vote the answer and accept it... This is the SO-way to say *thank you*...